# formatting local mobile to international in php

Tags: php, regex, mobile, formatting, sms

I am looking for a simple regex to convert both UK (44) and Indian (91) numbers into a valid international format using PHP. The formats required are:

```
447856555333 (for uk mobile numbers)
919876543456 (for indian mobile numbers)
```

I need a regex that will accept and format the following variations:

```
1) 07856555333
2) 0785 6555333
3) 0785 655 5333
4) 0785-655-5333
5) 00447856555333
6) 0044785 6555333
7) 0044785 655 5333
8) 0044785-655-5333
9) 00447856555333
10) +447856555333
11) +44785 6555333
12) +44785 655 5333
13) +44785-655-5333
14) +919876543456
15) 00919876543456
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: Based on answer below I have amended the code slightly and it works very well. It is not bullet proof but covers most of the popular formats:

```
    public static function formatMobile($mobile) {
        $locale = '44'; //need to update this
        $sms_country_codes = Config::get('sms_country_codes');

        //lose any non numeric characters
        $numeric_p_number = preg_replace("#[^0-9]+#", "", $mobile);
        //remove leading zeros
        $numeric_p_number = preg_replace("#^[0]*#", "", $numeric_p_number);
        //get first 2 digits
        $f2digit = substr($numeric_p_number, 0,2);

        if(strlen($numeric_p_number) == 12) {
            if(in_array($f2digit, $sms_country_codes) ) {
                //no looks ok 
            }
            else {
                return ""; //is correct length but missing country code so must be invalid!
            }
        }
        else {
            if(strlen($locale . $numeric_p_number) == 12 && !(in_array($f2digit, $sms_country_codes))) {
                $numeric_p_number = $locale . $numeric_p_number;
                //the number is ok after adding the country prefix
            } else {
                //something is missing from here
                return "";
            }
        }

        return $numeric_p_number;
    }
```

Comment: How do you know if "07856555333" is an English or an Indian number?

Comment: we can identify based on the locale, i.e. if the user submits their phone number on our .co.uk web site or our .co.in web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your particular scope think something like this might work ... not really a regex-only solution but should do the trick for your needs:

```
  $locale = "your_locale_prefix";
  $valid_codes = array("44","91");
  //loose any non numeric characters
  $numeric_p_number = preg_replace("#[^0-9]+#", "", $phone_number);
  //remove leading zeros
  $numeric_p_number = preg_replace("#^[0]*#", "", $numeric_p_number);
  //get first 2 digits
  $f2digit = substr($numeric_p_number, 0,2);
  if(in_array($f2digit, $valid_codes) && strlen($numeric_p_number) == 12){
         //code is ok 
  } else {
       if(strlen($locale . $numeric_p_number) == 12) {
           //the number is ok after adding the country prefix
       } else {
           //something is missing from here
       }
  }
```

Comment: Just tried and it works perfectly. If nothing is returned then its invalid. I'd +2 if I could :-)